# BSON data iteration

Tags: python, maas

I am calling the maas api to get the details of node. And I am getting the output as bson data. How can I iterate it. 
By searching I found that BSON package. But I want to use alternative of this. Can you please suggest other packages to do the job.

My maas api call is follows

```
resp = self.client.get(u"nodes/%s/" % node_id, "details")
```

print resp gives =>

```
<addinfourl at 139851033511408 whose fp = <gzip _io.BytesIO object at 0x7f319b4f7dd0 0x7f319b2abd50>>

print resp.header

Date: Tue, 28 Jun 2016 10:16:26 GMT
Server: TwistedWeb/13.2.0
Content-Length: 3007
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Authorization,Accept-Encoding,Cookie
X-Maas-Api-Hash: 0e5a2694573dce65d8051aa612b2ee9093b62c92
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: application/bson
Connection: close

print resp.read() Gives following o/p

> �8lldpF<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lldp label="LLDP neighbors"/>
lshwm8<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
<!-- generated by lshw-B.02.16 -->
<!-- GCC 4.8.4 -->
<!-- Linux 3.13.0-85-generic #129-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 17 20:50:15 UTC 2016 x86_64 -->
<!-- GNU libc 2 (glibc 2.19) -->
<list>
<node id="crisp-change" claimed="true" class="system" handle="DMI:0100">
 <description>Computer</description>
 <product>Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996) ()</product>
 <vendor>QEMU</vendor>
 <version>pc-i440fx-trusty</version>
 <width units="bits">64</width>
 <configuration>
  <setting id="boot" value="normal" />
  <setting id="uuid" value="B0E5BE78-766F-E75F-6509-14AD45C92EAB" />
 </configuration>
 <capabilities>
  <capability id="smbios-2.4" >SMBIOS version 2.4</capability>
  <capability id="dmi-2.4" >DMI version 2.4</capability>
  <capability id="vsyscall32" >32-bit processes</capability>
 </capabilities>
  <node id="core" claimed="true" class="bus" handle="">
   <description>Motherboard</description>
   <physid>0</physid>
    <node id="firmware" claimed="true" class="memory" handle="">
     <description>BIOS</description>
     <vendor>Bochs</vendor>
     <physid>0</physid>
     <version>Bochs</version>
     <date>01/01/2011</date>
     <size units="bytes">98304</size>
    </node>
    <node id="cpu" claimed="true" class="processor" handle="DMI:0401">
     <description>CPU</description>
     <product>QEMU Virtual CPU version 2.0.0</product>
     <vendor>Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]</vendor>
     <physid>401</physid>
     <businfo>cpu@0</businfo>
     <slot>CPU 1</slot>
     <size units="Hz">2000000000</size>
     <capacity units="Hz">2000000000</capacity>
     <width units="bits">64</width>
     <capabilities>
      <capability id="fpu" >mathematical co-processor</capability>
      <capability id="fpu_exception" >FPU exceptions reporting</capability>
      <capability id="wp" />
      <capability id="de" >debugging extensions</capability>
      <capability id="pse" >page size extensions</capability>
      <capability id="tsc" >time stamp counter</capability>
      <capability id="msr" >model-specific registers</capability>
      <capability id="pae" >4GB+ memory addressing (Physical Address Extension)</capability>
      <capability id="mce" >machine check exceptions</capability>
      <capability id="cx8" >compare and exchange 8-byte</capability>
      <capability id="apic" >on-chip advanced programmable interrupt controller (APIC)</capability>
      <capability id="sep" >fast system calls</capability>
      <capability id="mtrr" >memory type range registers</capability>
      <capability id="pge" >page global enable</capability>
      <capability id="mca" >machine check architecture</capability>
      <capability id="cmov" >conditional move instruction</capability>
      <capability id="pat" >page attribute table</capability>
      <capability id="pse36" >36-bit page size extensions</capability>
      <capability id="clflush" />
      <capability id="mmx" >multimedia extensions (MMX)</capability>
      <capability id="fxsr" >fast floating point save/restore</capability>
      <capability id="sse" >streaming SIMD extensions (SSE)</capability>
      <capability id="sse2" >streaming SIMD extensions (SSE2)</capability>
      <capability id="syscall" >fast system calls</capability>
      <capability id="nx" >no-execute bit (NX)</capability>
      <capability id="x86-64" >64bits extensions (x86-64)</capability>
      <capability id="nopl" />
      <capability id="pni" />
      <capability id="cx16" />
      <capability id="x2apic" />
      <capability id="popcnt" />
      <capability id="hypervisor" />
      <capability id="lahf_lm" />
      <capability id="svm" />
      <capability id="abm" />
      <capability id="sse4a" />
      <capability id="vmmcall" />
     </capabilities>
    </node>
    <node id="memory" claimed="true" class="memory" handle="DMI:1000">
     <description>System Memory</description>
     <physid>1000</physid>
     <size units="bytes">1073741824</size>
     <capacity units="bytes">1073741824</capacity>
      <node id="bank" claimed="true" class="memory" handle="DMI:1100">
       <description>DIMM RAM</description>
       <physid>0</physid>
       <slot>DIMM 0</slot>
       <size units="bytes">1073741824</size>
       <width units="bits">64</width>
      </node>
    </node>
    <node id="pci" claimed="true" class="bridge" handle="PCIBUS:0000:00">
     <description>Host bridge</description>
     <product>440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma]</product>
     <vendor>Intel Corporation</vendor>
     <physid>100</physid>
     <businfo>pci@0000:00:00.0</businfo>
     <version>02</version>
     <width units="bits">32</width>
     <clock units="Hz">33000000</clock>
      <node id="isa" claimed="true" class="bridge" handle="PCI:0000:00:01.0">
       <description>ISA bridge</description>
       <product>82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]</product>
       <vendor>Intel Corporation</vendor>
       <physid>1</physid>
       <businfo>pci@0000:00:01.0</businfo>
       <version>00</version>
       <width units="bits">32</width>
       <clock units="Hz">33000000</clock>
       <configuration>
        <setting id="latency" value="0" />
       </configuration>
       <capabilities>
        <capability id="isa" />
       </capabilities>
      </node>
      <node id="ide" claimed="true" class="storage" handle="PCI:0000:00:01.1">
       <description>IDE interface</description>
       <product>82371SB PIIX3 IDE [Natoma/Triton II]</product>
       <vendor>Intel Corporation</vendor>
       <physid>1.1</physid>
       <businfo>pci@0000:00:01.1</businfo>
       <version>00</version>
       <width units="bits">32</width>
       <clock units="Hz">33000000</clock>
       <configuration>
        <setting id="driver" value="ata_piix" />
        <setting id="latency" value="0" />
       </configuration>
       <capabilities>
        <capability id="ide" />
        <capability id="bus_master" >bus mastering</capability>
       </capabilities>
       <resources>
        <resource type="irq" value="0" />
        <resource type="ioport" value="1f0(size=8)" />
        <resource type="ioport" value="3f6" />
        <resource type="ioport" value="170(size=8)" />
        <resource type="ioport" value="376" />
        <resource type="ioport" value="c0a0(size=16)" />
       </resources>
      </node>
      <node id="usb" claimed="true" class="bus" handle="PCI:0000:00:01.2">
       <description>USB controller</description>
       <product>82371SB PIIX3 USB [Natoma/Triton II]</product>
       <vendor>Intel Corporation</vendor>
       <physid>1.2</physid>
       <businfo>pci@0000:00:01.2</businfo>
       <version>01</version>
       <width units="bits">32</width>
       <clock units="Hz">33000000</clock>
       <configuration>
        <setting id="driver" value="uhci_hcd" />
        <setting id="latency" value="0" />
       </configuration>
       <capabilities>
        <capability id="uhci" >Universal Host Controller Interface (USB1)</capability>
        <capability id="bus_master" >bus mastering</capability>
       </capabilities>
       <resources>
        <resource type="irq" value="11" />
        <resource type="ioport" value="c040(size=32)" />
       </resources>
      </node>
      <node id="bridge" claimed="true" class="bridge" handle="PCI:0000:00:01.3">
       <description>Bridge</description>
       <product>82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI</product>
       <vendor>Intel Corporation</vendor>
       <physid>1.3</physid>
       <businfo>pci@0000:00:01.3</businfo>
       <version>03</version>
       <width units="bits">32</width>
       <clock units="Hz">33000000</clock>
       <configuration>
        <setting id="driver" value="piix4_smbus" />
        <setting id="latency" value="0" />
       </configuration>
       <capabilities>
        <capability id="bridge" />
       </capabilities>
       <resources>
        <resource type="irq" value="9" />
       </resources>
      </node>
      <node id="display" class="display" handle="PCI:0000:00:02.0">
       <description>VGA compatible controller</description>
       <product>GD 5446</product>
       <vendor>Cirrus Logic</vendor>
       <physid>2</physid>
       <businfo>pci@0000:00:02.0</businfo>
       <version>00</version>
       <width units="bits">32</width>
       <clock units="Hz">33000000</clock>
       <configuration>
        <setting id="latency" value="0" />
       </configuration>
       <capabilities>
        <capability id="vga_controller" />
       </capabilities>
       <resources>
        <resource type="memory" value="fc000000-fdffffff" />
        <resource type="memory" value="febd0000-febd0fff" />
        <resource type="memory" value="febc0000-febcffff" />
       </resources>
      </node>
      <node id="network" claimed="true" class="network" handle="PCI:0000:00:03.0">
       <description>Ethernet interface</description>
       <product>Virtio network device</product>
       <vendor>Red Hat, Inc</vendor>
       <physid>3</physid>
       <businfo>pci@0000:00:03.0</businfo>
       <logicalname>eth0</logicalname>
       <version>00</version>
       <serial>52:54:00:c4:65:b4</serial>
       <width units="bits">32</width>
       <clock units="Hz">33000000</clock>
       <configuration>
        <setting id="broadcast" value="yes" />
        <setting id="driver" value="virtio_net" />
        <setting id="driverversion" value="1.0.0" />
        <setting id="ip" value="10.20.0.151" />
        <setting id="latency" value="0" />
        <setting id="link" value="yes" />
        <setting id="multicast" value="yes" />
       </configuration>
       <capabilities>
        <capability id="msix" >MSI-X</capability>
        <capability id="bus_master" >bus mastering</capability>
        <capability id="cap_list" >PCI capabilities listing</capability>
        <capability id="rom" >extension ROM</capability>
        <capability id="ethernet" />
        <capability id="physical" >Physical interface</capability>
       </capabilities>
       <resources>
        <resource type="irq" value="10" />
        <resource type="ioport" value="c060(size=32)" />
        <resource type="memory" value="febd1000-febd1fff" />
        <resource type="memory" value="feb80000-febbffff" />
       </resources>
      </node>
      <node id="scsi" claimed="true" class="storage" handle="PCI:0000:00:04.0">
       <description>SCSI storage controller</description>
       <product>Virtio block device</product>
       <vendor>Red Hat, Inc</vendor>
       <physid>4</physid>
       <businfo>pci@0000:00:04.0</businfo>
       <version>00</version>
       <width units="bits">32</width>
       <clock units="Hz">33000000</clock>
       <configuration>
        <setting id="driver" value="virtio-pci" />
        <setting id="latency" value="0" />
       </configuration>
       <capabilities>
        <capability id="scsi" />
        <capability id="msix" >MSI-X</capability>
        <capability id="bus_master" >bus mastering</capability>
        <capability id="cap_list" >PCI capabilities listing</capability>
       </capabilities>
       <resources>
        <resource type="irq" value="11" />
        <resource type="ioport" value="c000(size=64)" />
        <resource type="memory" value="febd2000-febd2fff" />
       </resources>
      </node>
      <node id="generic" claimed="true" class="generic" handle="PCI:0000:00:05.0">
       <description>Unclassified device</description>
       <product>Virtio memory balloon</product>
       <vendor>Red Hat, Inc</vendor>
       <physid>5</physid>
       <businfo>pci@0000:00:05.0</businfo>
       <version>00</version>
       <width units="bits">32</width>
       <clock units="Hz">33000000</clock>
       <configuration>
        <setting id="driver" value="virtio-pci" />
        <setting id="latency" value="0" />
       </configuration>
       <capabilities>
        <capability id="bus_master" >bus mastering</capability>
       </capabilities>
       <resources>
        <resource type="irq" value="10" />
        <resource type="ioport" value="c080(size=32)" />
       </resources>
      </node>
    </node>
    <node id="scsi" claimed="true" class="storage" handle="">
     <physid>1</physid>
     <logicalname>scsi2</logicalname>
      <node id="generic" class="generic" handle="SCSI:02:00:00:00">
       <description>SCSI</description>
       <product>Controller</product>
       <vendor>IET</vendor>
       <physid>0.0.0</physid>
       <businfo>scsi@2:0.0.0</businfo>
       <version>0001</version>
       <serial>beaf10</serial>
       <configuration>
        <setting id="ansiversion" value="5" />
       </configuration>
      </node>
      <node id="disk" claimed="true" class="volume" handle="SCSI:02:00:00:01">
       <description>EXT4 volume</description>
       <product>VIRTUAL-DISK</product>
       <vendor>Linux</vendor>
       <physid>0.0.1</physid>
       <businfo>scsi@2:0.0.1</businfo>
       <logicalname>/dev/sda</logicalname>
       <logicalname>/media/root-ro</logicalname>
       <dev>8:0</dev>
       <version>1.0</version>
       <serial>6872cb1e-3766-4ff3-9de5-11ffd99c3fc9</serial>
       <size units="bytes">1468006400</size>
       <configuration>
        <setting id="ansiversion" value="5" />
        <setting id="created" value="2016-04-18 16:39:57" />
        <setting id="filesystem" value="ext4" />
        <setting id="label" value="cloudimg-rootfs" />
        <setting id="lastmountpoint" value="/tmp/copy-source-to-target.qeycvT/tgt" />
        <setting id="modified" value="2016-04-18 16:40:52" />
        <setting id="mount.fstype" value="ext4" />
        <setting id="mount.options" value="ro,relatime,data=ordered" />
        <setting id="mounted" value="2016-04-18 16:39:58" />
        <setting id="sectorsize" value="4096" />
        <setting id="state" value="mounted" />
       </configuration>
       <capabilities>
        <capability id="journaled" />
        <capability id="extended_attributes" >Extended Attributes</capability>
        <capability id="large_files" >4GB+ files</capability>
        <capability id="huge_files" >16TB+ files</capability>
        <capability id="dir_nlink" >directories with 65000+ subdirs</capability>
        <capability id="extents" >extent-based allocation</capability>
        <capability id="ext4" />
        <capability id="ext2" >EXT2/EXT3</capability>
        <capability id="initialized" >initialized volume</capability>
       </capabilities>
      </node>
    </node>
  </node>
</node>
</list>
```

How can I Iterate the values from this.

Comment: It's not BSON, it's XML.

Comment: Hi enedil,   
Following is the header of the response , 
Date: Tue, 28 Jun 2016 10:20:57 GMT
Server: TwistedWeb/13.2.0
Content-Length: 3007
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Authorization,Accept-Encoding,Cookie
X-Maas-Api-Hash: 0e5a2694573dce65d8051aa612b2ee9093b62c92
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: application/bson
Connection: close

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using the USE team's MAAS client, from https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/maasclient. That client returns data from queries in BSON format.

To parse BSON output, use the Python BSON package: https://github.com/py-bson/bson

Here's how you'd read the data in your case:

```
import bson

resp = self.client.get(u"nodes/%s/" % node_id, "details")
data = bytes(rest.read(), "utf8")
node_details = bson.loads(data)
```

NOTE: I'd like to update this answer with an example, which will need to wait until my MAAS 2.0 installation is updated.

If you'd rather not get BSON, then you should look at using the simple MAAS client which is currently bundled with MAAS itself. I'll also update the answer with details on that.

Comment: thank you kiko. Please update it when you get it. I don't want to use BSON in my code